# File.AppendText attempting to write to wrong location

Tags: c#, file, console, streamwriter

I have a C# console application that runs as a scheduled task within Windows Task Scheduler. This console app writes to a log file that when runs within debug mode creates and writes to the file within the application folder itself. However, when it runs in the task scheduler it throws an error saying that access is denied because it is trying to write to the same log file, but for some reason it is trying to write to it within the windows\system32 folder. Why would this be happening? And how would I correct this?

Here is the code snippet that assigns a StreamWriter to the log file:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (_swrtr = File.AppendText("gapi_gen_log.txt")) 
    {
        _swrtr.Write("\r\n");
        _swrtr.Write("\r\nGOOGLE CALENDAR:");
        _swrtr.Write("\r\n\tDate Time - " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        start();
    }
}
```

I also tried but this didn't work:

```
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        using (_swrtr = File.AppendText(dir + "gapi_gen_log.txt")) 
        {
            _swrtr.Write("\r\n");
            _swrtr.Write("\r\nGOOGLE CALENDAR:");
            _swrtr.Write("\r\n\tDate Time - " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            start();
        }
```

Comment: Because it is running from the Windows Task Scheduler, and you are specifying a relative path.

Comment: The question is: what target path do you expect at all? Use an absolute path to a directory like `D:\Google-Calendar\Logs\gapi_gen_log.txt`.

Comment: And... what is `start()` doing... Is it disposing of the lock on the File

Comment: @Nico: start() is running a few processes and writing to the log file (Which everything runs perfect in debug mode)

Comment: @Tim: I was going to use absolute however, since this will be going onto a web server I will not know exactly where it is going to be placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are not specifying a directory for your log file, so it's assuming the directory where the parent executable resides which, while you're debugging, is your debug output folder and when you're running it from the task scheduler, is the "c:\windows\system32" folder.

You could provide a path to the directory like this:

```
File.AppendText(@"c:\MyLogFiles\gapi_gen_log.txt")
```

Comment: I ended up coding to create a directory under C: wherever this application will be placed and write the file there. Thank you roryap, and everyone else.